# orderBy not working on Angularfire Array

Tags: angularjs, angularfire

I have an array that comes from Angularfire $asArray.  Can't figure out why normal `orderby` won't work on it.

Here's the line that's the kicker:

```
ng-repeat="show in shows[0] | orderBy:'price'"
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/i3QqSOxTtJpXBo0qsQds?p=preview)

Comment: orederBy does not work on objects, you have to use also toArray. ng-repeat="show in shows[0] | toArray | orderBy:'price'"

Comment: Thanks @Piyush.  I saw that on some other answers.  What I have is an Array of objects.  From what I saw on other answers, that doesn't apply to an array of objects.

Comment: So is it worked for you or not?

Comment: Did not work. That's a jQuery method and I'm trying do the angular way.